# Conv1D does not update the weights. (All zero) and Test outputs are always same which is equal to Last layer Weights?

Tags: python, keras, time-series, conv-neural-network

I would like to use 1D CNN to predict next day solar energy. The time series data resolution is one hour and the length is one year. I am training the model with the data of day 1 to predict day 2. xtrain = day1, ytrain = day2, xtest = day3 to predict day4.

24 hour data input -> CNN -> 24 hour output

I have trained the data for 10 days (samples); then predicted 4 days in advance, the problem is that CNN always gives the same output value whatever the input is. Then, I checked the weights, only output layer weights are nonzero. Also, the output value does not change with different set of input.

The link for the data: https://mega.nz/#!NpoTzIBJ!U5l8ToQgcJ6xif2tMjIrXuace3skhrtwLEdeoWe_FkM

The image of weight matrix:
[image: weights]

The graph of Predicted Values:
[image: preds]

Code:

```
import pandas
from pandas import Series
from pandas import DataFrame
import keras
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation, regularizers, initializers
from keras.layers import Conv1D,  MaxPooling1D, Flatten, AveragePooling1D
from keras.activations import *
from keras.losses import *
from keras.optimizers import *
from keras.utils import plot_model
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.utils import plot_model
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import preprocessing
from numpy import zeros, newaxis
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
import sklearn.metrics
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from math import sqrt

data = pandas.read_csv("meas.csv", header=0)
dataset = data.values[:,1]

all_pred_data = []
ytest_all = []

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(3,kernel_size=3,activation='relu', input_shape=xtrain.shape[1:3],kernel_initializer=initializers.RandomUniform(minval=-1, maxval=1),kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.1))) #input_shape=()
model.add(AveragePooling1D(pool_size=3))
model.add(Conv1D(3,kernel_size=3,activation='relu', input_shape=xtrain.shape[1:3],kernel_initializer=initializers.RandomUniform(minval=-1, maxval=1),kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.1))) #input_shape=()
model.add(AveragePooling1D(pool_size=3))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(42,activation='tanh',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.1),kernel_initializer=initializers.RandomUniform(minval=-1, maxval=1)))
model.add(Dense(24, activation='linear',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.1),kernel_initializer=initializers.RandomUniform(minval=-1, maxval=1)))

model.compile(loss='mse',
          optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
          metrics=['mae','accuracy'])


for i in range(0,10-1,1): 

    xtrain = dataset[24*(i+1)-24:24*(i+1)]
    ytrain = dataset[24*(i+1):24*(i+2)]

    xtrain = xtrain.reshape(1,24,1)
    ytrain = ytrain.reshape(1,24)

    model.fit(xtrain,ytrain,epochs=500,verbose=2) 


# TEST
for i in range(20,25-1,1):
    xtest = dataset[24*(i+1):24*(i+2)] #(i+1):(i+6+1)
    ytest = dataset[24*(i+2):24*(i+2)+24]

    xtest = xtest.reshape(1,xtrain.shape[1], 1)

    pred_data = np.round(model.predict(xtest),3)

    pred_data_transpose = pred_data.transpose()

    all_pred_data.extend(pred_data_transpose)
    ytest_all.extend(np.round(ytest,3))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the weight went all to 0 they will never change because the gradient will always be 0, to avoid this try to normalize your data which make it easier to train the network, try also to use batch_normalization if normalizing the input data wasn't enough

Comment: The data is already normalized. CNN weights are zero, but the last dense layer weights are non-zero

Comment: if the CNN weights are zero the output of that layer will always be zero so it's normal that the output of the following layers will always be the same. if your data is already normalized (0 mean and 1 variance) try to decrease the learning rate, add batch normalization before every convolution, try different weight initialization for the convolution, xavier (the default initializer for conv in keras) is usually pretty good. To see if the learning rate is too big look how long it takes to the network to output always the same result, if this happen pretty fast it's clear that ur LR is too big.